# How to store the external webservice response value in a flow variable using Enricher

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am stuck with a minor issue .. There is My Mule flow ..
I am passing a SOAP payload to an external webservice from a Message Enricher component and the Idea is to get a particular attribute value from the external webservice response and store that value in a flow variable ...
Now, the response of the external webservice response is as follow :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <getDesignationResponse xmlns="http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <DesignationCodeResult>Junior Developer</DesignationCodeResult>
         <Code>Success</Code>
      </getDesignationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now here is my flow :-

```
 <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
   <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>

<set-payload value="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><v1:getDesignationRequest><v1:DesignationCode>jd</v1:DesignationCode></v1:getDesignationRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

  <enricher source="#[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]" target="#[variable:myVal]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
  <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8090/designation" responseTimeout="100000" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>

     <logger message="Value from response #[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </processor-chain>           
</enricher> 

</flow>
```

Now you can see I am trying to store the value `#[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]` to the Flow Variable **myVal** ..

Now I am getting following exception :-

```
Exception stack is:
1. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:myVal" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException)
  org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils:235 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/RequiredValueException.html)
2. Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:myVal" returned null but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:myVal" returned null but a value was required.
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getPropertyInternal(ExpressionUtils.java:235)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getProperty(ExpressionUtils.java:85)
    at org.mule.expression.ExpressionUtils.getProperty(ExpressionUtils.java:72)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

But I have put a logger inside the **Enricher**  `<logger message="Value from response #[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` and I am getting the value there ..
But I am unable to assign the extracted value in the Flow Variable using Enricher ...
Please help ..

Comment: What if you remove the logger? I'm wondering if you are consuming the HTTP response input stream with the logger, thus making it unavailable for the enricher...

Comment: Tried with removing the logger from Enricher ... Same exception I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add namespace support:

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="vertu" uri="http://services.vertu.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Then stop using the old deprecated expression syntax and use MEL instead:

```
<enricher
    source="#[xpath('//vertu:getDesignationResponse/vertu:DesignationCodeResult/text()').text]"
    target="#[flowVars['myVal']]">
```

Also if you want to keep the logger, add an `object-to-string-transformer` after the inbound HTTP endpoint in order to deserialize the response input stream to a `String`, which would be readable multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

From the post if can be seen that the Response being posted has a namespace

```
xmlns="http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1"
```

The namespace http://services.test.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1   should be registered in your mule config XML namespace manager.

Then the xpath will be able to recognize the xml element from the response properly

**Updated answer based on the comment:**

Try the following modified enricher part of your flow.

```
<enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[variable:myVal]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:8090/designation" responseTimeout="100000" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <logger message="Value from response #[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <set-payload value="#[xpath://getDesignationResponse/DesignationCodeResult]" />
              </processor-chain>           
</enricher>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes It's already done and I am getting the value of DesignationCodeResult in logger inside Enricher .. but unable to set it in flow variable of enricher

Comment: You were right .. there were slight issue with namespace .. need to modify the namespace and XPATH for that .. anyways +1 for your great suggestion.. David's suggestion worked for me .. But many many thanks for your help ..

Answer (score 0):

So, As per David's suggestion , the solution is to correct the namespace issue , and the working code is :-

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="soapenv" uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <mulexml:namespace prefix="vertu" uri="http://services.vertu.getDesignation.com/schema/MainData/V1"/>
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```